# Change Windows password from php

Tags: php, windows, iis, passwords, exec

Im looking for a way of changing a Windows password on my server from PHP. At the moment my server is running Windows 7 x64, IIS 7.5 and php 5.3. I would like a user to be able to change their individual password from my web application.

I have tried exec("net user Jack 123"), this runs as isur or somthing like that on the server in task manager and I think that that user, "isur", cant change passwords.
I have also tried running my site as different app pools and users including Admin but nothing seems to work.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: I might be wrong but i do not think there is ANY way you can do this. If you could there would be a ton of viruses taking over everyone's computers...

Comment: does the `net user Jack 123` command work if you run it normally from command prompt?

Comment: Vague thoughts of getting the user to provide current and new passwords, then using a 'runas' script to to assume that user's credentials and changing the pw that way, but it's just a vague idea and probably wouldn't work.

Comment: joshb   "net user Jack 123" does work

Comment: I know there is a way with LDAP / Domain, but im just doing this for my family....all four of us.

Comment: I dont really want to use AD...

Comment: Still getting nowhere...any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to combine the `net user` command with [`runas`](https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows).  Still would advise against exposing this functionality outside of the machine it'll run on.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149427
Microsoft supports changing passwords from command line. Also there are ASP pages and scripts to the same: example: http://www.quest.com/password-manager/

In your case, try coding php script to run the net commands as mentioned in microsoft support page. BUT, the key thing is to make sure the script runs in admin account.

Try that out and share your result !

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to get the script to run as an Admin... if i type "exec("start notepad")" and run the page with that code, in my task manager, I see notpad.exe running as iusr. So it is working from php to cmd, but just cant change the password or perform admin tasks